# Reshape MxN cell array to 1x(M*N) cell array MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell, legend, cell-array

I am trying to make a cell array for legend titles in a plot. The plot has repetitions of an experiment with different frequencies and 3 different sensors. I need a different colour for each different sensor and frequency. Hence in the following example with two frequencies I end up with a 3x2 cell array where I need the array in one dimension to use as a legend (6x1) but I can't figure how to achieve this.

```
titles = {'Radial Sensor';'Axial Sensor';'Azimuthal Sensor'};

for ii=1:3 
    for jj = 1:num_freq
        legtitles{ii,jj} = [titles{ii},' ',num2str(freq(jj)),' Hz'];
    end
end
```

Ans:

```
'Radial Sensor 15 Hz'       'Radial Sensor 60 Hz'
'Axial Sensor 15 Hz'        'Axial Sensor 60 Hz'
'Azimuthal Sensor 15 Hz'    'Azimuthal Sensor 60 Hz'
```

So, I need to take the second and third rows and concatenate them onto the end of the first.

Thanks!

Comment: So you want`'Radial Sensor 15 Hz'       'Radial Sensor 60 Hz'
'Axial Sensor 15 Hz'`... all in one row?

Comment: Yep, thanks! Both the answers I got work. I don't know why I didn't see that immediately.

Comment: @Rollolol Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If an answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You could either reshape your final legtitles:

```
legtitles = reshape(legtitles',1,[]);
```

or rewrite your code to:

```
legtitles = {}
for ...
    for ...
        legtitles{end+1} = ...
```

Comment: Rewriting the code as you say is probably the best solution (preallocating is not very important for small arrays). +1

Answer (score 0):

To concatenate all rows into a single row: if you have

```
legtitles = {'Radial Sensor 15 Hz'       'Radial Sensor 60 Hz';
             'Axial Sensor 15 Hz'        'Axial Sensor 60 Hz';
             'Azimuthal Sensor 15 Hz'    'Azimuthal Sensor 60 Hz'};
```

just use

```
legtitles = legtitles.';
legtitles = legtitles(:).';
```